# More/Less Html Script Fail

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to open a long text by clicking on (More) and close again by clicking on (Less). It runs fine only when I click on More the further text does not open.

I use woocommerce, and would like to insert an individual field for a product, in this field should be a short description of the product, I would like to include the text with More and less.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "More";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Less";
    moreText.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {
  display: none;
}

#myBtn {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

#myBtn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -3px;
  background: #242424;
}

p {
  max-width: 390px;
  font-size: .9rem;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gillsans, sans-serif;
  color: #242424;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span id="dots">A strong, masculine fragrance, Dylan Blue encapsulates the sensual scents of the Mediterranean. The fragrance bold ambrox notes, refreshed w<span id="dots">...</span></span>
  <span id="more">A strong, masculine fragrance, Dylan Blue encapsulates the sensual scents of the Mediterranean. The fragrance bold ambrox notes, refreshed with hints of bergamot and grapefruit. The earthy and citrusy olfactory notes are enveloped with black pepper, papyrus wood and incense, along with mineral musk, tonka beans and saffron. The bold perfume is stored in a blue, geometric bottle enriched with gold tone accents, evoking the Mediterranean Sea and sand.</span>
  <a onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">More</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Just use plain html <details> element..

Comment: Your snippet was incorrectly formatted and when I fixed it the code seems to work fine